# What's the difference between a hug and a handshake?

Tags: php, handshake

While reading the [PSR-8 draft](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/psr-8-hug/psr-8-hug.md), I am trying to determine if what the author is referring to is indeed synonymous to a handshake.  Handshaking often involves establishing certain parameters, but I don't see anything like that required in the PSR, but the language doesn't exclude each object performing other operations while hugging.  Or is the author simply being cute?

Comment: The document was first committed on April 1, 2014. Does that tell you anything?

Comment: After reading it, I find it probably shares much of the same intent behind https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2324.txt

Comment: I'm guessing huggers can't hug handshakers and vice-versa.